# Instantiate an object named in a variable

Tags: python, object, instantiation

I have a library of component objects.  I would like to include instantiations of a selection of those objects in another object. But I would like to provide that selection as a list so that each time I instantiate the container object with a list, it will be created with the specified sub objects in it.

Let's say my component library looks like this:

```
class ColorBlob(object):
    ...
    def wipeItUp()
        ...

class RedBlob(ColorBlob):
    ...
    def paintIt()
        ...
class YellowBlob(ColorBlob):
    ...
    def paintIt()
        ...
class BlueBlob(ColorBlob):
    ...
    def paintIt()
        ...
```

And my container object looks like this:

```
class Pallet(object):
    def __init__(self, colorList):
        for color in colorList:
            #Ok, here is where I get lost if I know the color I can do this:
            Pallet.BlueBlob = blobLib.BlueBlob()
            #But I don't, so I am trying to do something like this:
            blobSpecs       = getattr(blobLib, color)
            blobSpecs.Obj   = blobSpecs().returnObj(self.page) # with "returnObj" defined in the library as some other method
            setattr(self, Pallet.blobName, blobSpecs) #and I am completely lost.
```

But what I really want to do in my functional code is this:

```
workingPallet=Pallet(['RedBlob', 'BlueBlob'])
workingPallet.RedBlob.paintIt()
```

I know that I am lost when I try to instantiate the sub objects in the container.  Can someone help me straighten out my "getattr" and "setattr" nonsense?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the caps problem

Comment: so, setting `setattr(self, color, blobSpecs)` doesn't work for you?

Comment: No, I end up with unbound methods.

Comment: Bingo, that's important information, the errors you get when you run into problems. :-)

Comment: Oh?  I should include the actual error?  Not just whine about my crappy code? (sarcaem at self)

Comment: It helps show us where your thinking went and what went wrong.

Comment: Not 100% on what you are trying to do with `.returnObj(self.page)` there. How is that defined, and what is it's purpose? What does it return?

Comment: A dictionary would probably make a lot of sense here. `{cls.__name__: cls for cls in ColorBlob.__subclasses__()}` for example.

Comment: oh, the ".returnObj" is from my actual code.  It is really the goal of the whole process.  My subObjects should include some attributes and an object that is pulled from somewhere else.  Then I can use my subObjects as a handle on the whole mess.  I put my question in terms of colors and pallets to make it clearer what I was asking.  Just think of ".returnObj" as some method that snags an object and stuffs it in an attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there, but it isn't your `getattr` or `setattr` that's the problem. You end up setting the class back on `self`, not the instance you created:

```
def __init__(self, colorList):
    for color in colorList:
        blobSpec       = getattr(blobLib, color)
        blob           = blobSpec()    # create an instance of the blob
        blob.Obj       = blob.returnObj(self.page) 
        setattr(self, color, blob)
```

It's the same thing as calling the class directly (`BlueBlob()`), but now through a variable.

Comment: That did it.  Creating an instance of the blob was the little bit I was missing.  Should have been obvious.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and I edited the last line of my code to include the "()" to call the method.  Just to keep my question clear for whoever comes next.